# how to upload new photos in edit action view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using devise for authentication.user can have many albums.i have album controller and view.i have photo modelalso.

association is user can have many albums and album can have many photos.
 i am using nested attributes for table photo. using carrier wave for photo upload.i am able to upload new photos in new.html.erb view during  creation   of  new album.
able to remove and update photo in edit.html.erb view.But i am not able to upload new photo in edit.html.erb file

this is albumscontroller

```
    class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
     before_action :authenticate_user!
```

these are controller actions

```
     def index
    @albums = current_user.albums.all
    end

      def show
      @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])

      end

     def new
     @album = current_user.albums.new
     @album.photos.new
     3.times { @album.photos.build }
     end

    def edit 
    @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])

     end

    def create
    @album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)

    if @album.save
    redirect_to action: 'index'
    else
    render 'new'
    end
    end

    def update
    @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])

    if @album.update(album_params)
    @album.save

    redirect_to action: 'show'
    else
     render 'edit'
     end
    end


     def destroy
     @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
     @album.destroy
     redirect_to action: 'index'

     end


      private
   def album_params                                                         
   params.require(:album).permit(:title,:description 
               photos_attributes[:id,:avatar,:_destroy])
      end

     end
```

this is new.html.erb file for creation of new album

```
         <h1>New Album</h1>

    <%= form_for @album, as: :album, url: user_albums_path, multipart: true 

    do |f| %>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
     </p>
```

for photo upload

```
        <p>
       <%= f.fields_for :photos do|i| %>
        <%= i.file_field :avatar %>
        <% end %> 
       </p>
       <p>
        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
       <%= f.submit %>
        </p>
         <% end %>
```

this is edit.html.erb where i have created edit view

```
             <h1> Edit Your Album </h1>
```

this is form to edit album

```
    <%= form_for @album, as: :album, :url=> {:controller => "albums",:action

    => "update" }, method: :put do |f| %>
     <p>
     <%= f.label :title %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
       </p>

       <p>
      <%= f.label :description %><br>
       <%= f.text_area :description %>
       </p>

         <p>
      <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
      <td>
      <% for photo in @album.photos %>
       <%= image_tag photo.avatar_url.to_s %>
       <% end %>
       </td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
     <%= f.fields_for :photos do |builder| %>

      <%= builder.check_box :_destroy %>
      <%= builder.label :_destroy, "remove" %>
      <% end %>
       </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
       </p>
      <h3>Update</h3>
       <p>
      <%= f.fields_for :photos do|i| %>
       <%= i.file_field :avatar %>
         <% end %> 
     </p>


      <p>
       <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
        <%= f.submit %>
      </p>


        <% end %>




      <%= link_to 'Back',user_albums_path %>
```

this is album.rb where i have defined nested attribures and destroy properties.
this model has many association with user model.

```
        class Album < ActiveRecord::Base

       has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
       belongs_to :user
       accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true,

        :update_only =>true
        end
```

this is photo.rb file of photo model where i have defined mount uploader of named avatar created using carreirwave
this model has many association with album

```
          class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
          mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
          belongs_to :album

          end
```

please tell me how i can upload new photo during edit action

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `3.times { @album.photos.build }` in your edit action too like new action in AlbumsController?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `multipart: true` in your **edit** form.